# To make the alternating group a topological group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, finite-groups, topological-groups

Let $n \ge 5$ . How many distinct topologies (not necessarily Hausdorff) can be given to the group $A_n$ so that it becomes a topological group ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a possibly non-Hausdorff topological group, the closure of the identity
is a normal subgroup. In a finite simple group this is either the whole
group, so the topology is indiscrete, or the identity subgroup, so the topology is Hausdorff, which for a finite set must be discrete.

Comment: I know that in a topological group , the connected component of identity is a closed and normal subgroup ... but how do you say that the closure of identity is normal subgroup ?

Comment: @users Conjugation by a fixed element is a homeomorphism from the group to itself.

Comment: I still can't see how the closure is a subgroup .... once it is subgroup , I can see the normality ...

Comment: @users In a topological group, the closure of any subgroup is also a subgroup.